# How to pass a ref down more than one level in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, use-ref

I can pass a `<Parent />` ref to the `<Children />` through the `forwardRef`:

```
const Children = forwardRef((
  props, ref) => {

  return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>
})

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef()

  console.log('ref', ref)
  return (
    <Children ref={ref}>I'm a child</Children>
  );
}
```

But when I add one more level to `<GrandChildren />` the ref returns always undefined.

```
const GrandChildren = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>
})

const Children = forwardRef((
  props, ref) => {

  return <div><GrandChildren ref={ref} /></div>
})

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef()

  console.log('ref', ref)
  return (
    <Children ref={ref}>I'm a child</Children>
  );
}
```

I'm aware we can do this with Context and avoid the prop drilling but for this specific example I'd rather go for prop drilling. any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you have is to pass the ref as a prop name rather than `ref`.  For example:

```
import { useRef, forwardRef } from "react"

const GrandChildren = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>
})

const Children = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.children}
            <GrandChildren ref={props.grandchildenRef}>
                I'm a grandchild
            </GrandChildren>
        </div>
    )
}

export default function App() {
    const ref = useRef()
    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log("ref", ref)
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            <Children grandchildenRef={ref}>I'm a child</Children>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I copied your exact code (without an extra ")" in Children) to a sandbox and the ref returns undefined anyway

Comment: I have adjusted the code and fixed the bug.  Refs are not set until the component is rendered, therefore when you console.log before the return, the ref has not been set yet.  I have modeled the code to add an onClick on a wrapping div that will console.log the ref value when clicking on the wrapper which properly shows ref.current is the grandchild div.